# How to prevent class member obfuscation when using multiple classes related classes?

Tags: android, proguard

I have the following location in my project:

```
package com.example.data
```

Where I have placed four classes, A, B, C and D that look like this:

```
public class A {
    public List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class B {
    public List<C> CList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class C {
    public D d;
}

public class D {
    public String s;
}
```

Now, in my ProGuard I can add simething like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.data.data.A{*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.example.data.data.B{*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.example.data.data.C{*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.example.data.data.D{*;}
```

But is there a more simpler way I can avoid obfuscation in my classes configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a rule to the `package` level. So all `classes` under this package will not be `obfuscated`. In your `proguard` rules file, for example in `proguard-common.pro` file, add the below code.

```
-keep class com.example.data.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Not yet, just added my app to Google Play and wait for the update to be live. Once it's live, I get back to you. I'll will not forget the accept your answer if it will work.

Comment: Don't do like this, you should create release build and test in your device then only go to release in play store. otherwise, you need to update the app again and again. It's not a good method for every app uploading to play store

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll do it that way next time. However, the problem of obfuscation take place only when the app is added to Google Play, otherwise it works perfectly fine.